# Matlab 'wtifc' error when opening .tif files

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, tiff

I am having an issue opening .tif files on Matlab2022b. I am trying to crop images in a certain way with a script but having issues with it. Whenever I run the script I get the following output:

```
Error using wtifc
TIFF library error - 'TIFFOpenW:
C:\Users\..\crop_file_1.tif: Cannot open.'

Error in writetif (line 110)
wtifc(data, map, filename, writemode, colorspace, required_tags);

Error in imwrite (line 566)
        feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});

Error in file_cropper (line 758)
                    imwrite( im22(:,:,1),  File.Name(ii).Cropfile, 'compression', 'none') ;
```

I have tried to search for the issue and saw some similar issues but nothing fixed it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

I am trying to crop existing tif images in a certain way for further processing. However, after the second image the script fails.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [edit] the question accordingly.